# How to build next.js production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I try to get a production build in next.js to run it on my server but I can't build next.js production build when I try

> npm run build

Does anyone know how to get a prod build in next.js working correctly I did everything in the next.js documentation but always get this error below. If I do a dev build it works just fine but trying prod build results in errors.

I did also **next build** many times and reinstalled all node_modules packages still having this error.

**it always shows me in terminal**

```
Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:753:15)
    at new Server (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:80:25)
    at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:6:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/next.config.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadConfig (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:47:28)
    at _callee2$ (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:52:42)
    at tryCatch (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/mnt/c/Users/NZXT_YOLO/Desktop/New folder (2)/learnnextjs-demo/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-next@1.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-next@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kk/.npm/_logs/2018-12-10T19_58_00_588Z-debug.log
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

next.config.js

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("/projects/:page", (req, res) => {
    const page = req.params.page;
    let file = "";
    switch (page) {
      case "example1":
        file = "/projects/example1";
        break;
      case "example2":
        file = "/projects/example2";
        break;
    }
    return app.render(req, res, file, { page });
  });

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "video-react": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

I plan to run this next.js site using node on my AWS server. But to do this I need to get production build of react.js currently I can run just a development build.

Comment: Add this line in `package.json`: `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"`
Use `npm start` after `npm run build`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems your `server.js` config is not correct. Please try moving all you have from your `next.config.js` to `server.js` make sure the `next.config.js` file is empty then create a new npm run script:

```
"prod_start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

Your `package.json` should then look like this:

```
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "prod_start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "video-react": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

make sure to run: `npm run build && npm run prod_start`

Then you should have a production build of react running using next.js

Let me know if you got question.

Comment: This is so simple, now it works don't know what to say. Thanks so much! Really appreciated your help.

Comment: @Karim, I am using similar setup (express + next.js), can you please tell me how to build and deploy next.js app. When run next build command, it generates .next folder. I am not getting if I need to move all my app source (server.js etc.) to production server and run npm start, as my express.js server files are not moving/bundling to .next folder.

Comment: @RakeshRawat did u found out the solution to your problem, I am having the same doubts :(

Comment: Why ``node server.js`` and not ``next start`` ?

Comment: pm2 start npm --name "next-app" -- start this also help

Answer (score 45):

`next build` followed by `next start` should be the right commands to prepare the build for production and run it.

Here's an example for `package.json`. if you want to export application to run as a static content, something like hosting it in s3 as a static website, you need to run `next export`

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export"
}
...
```

Make sure you have the above scripts in your `package.json` then run the following in order

```
$ npm run build 
$ npm run start
```

If you want to start application with specific port, you can specify `-p` port as argument for `npm run` command

```
npm run start -- -p 3232
```

If you want to incorporate this into a CI/CD pipeline, you need to have `Dockerfile`, here's a simple example

```
FROM node:alpine

#copy source 
COPY . /app

# Install deps 
RUN cd /app &&  npm install 

# Build 
RUN npm run build

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Still need more explanation or help, don't hesitate to leave a comment and I will be more than happy to assist.

Comment: Why do `COPY . /app` and `cd /app`? Use `WORKDIR /app` and then `.` in place of the `/app` directory.

Comment: @Muhammad Soliman:  I am new to NEXT.JS, could you please let me know what is the reason for 'npm run start'? usually in react we don't execute that command, we directly point build directory to domain.

Comment: @TejasPatel `npm run start` should run the specified script called `start` in `package.json` - you could name the script `start` whatever you want though. in such case it would be `npm run <script_name>`

Comment: @ErikE this was just for clarifying the purpose of commands in a simple way to  make it easy for beginner readers to understand.

Comment: @MuhammadSoliman Understood, but we also need to teach beginners how to write their Dockerfiles "the Docker way," not write them idiosyncratically. Understanding `WORKDIR` is so fundamental to Dockerfiles, that giving beginners an answer that doesn't incorporate it is more likely to handicap them than to really help them, unless you give them a BIG hint in your answer, "Do not use this file as-is. You should leverage WORKDIR to write Dockerfiles properly." with a link to the correct docs or a stackoverflow answer on how to use WORKDIR correctly.

Comment: Doesn't work :D

Answer (score 1):

You must launch `next build` at your root folder and not inside `.next/`

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 ways todo it:-

way 1: use `next build` instead of `npm run build`

way 2: `npm run build` `npm install -g serve` `serve -s build`
more info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

way 3: after `npm run build`, Remove `/` from JS,CSS links from `/static/index.html` file. eg. replace these 2 lines

```
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.aa87bc08.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

with these 2 lines

```
<script defer="defer" src="static/js/main.aa87bc08.js"></script>
<link href="static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

now it even work on file:///D:/codes/ProjectName/build/index.html

tell me in the comments if none of the 3 ways work, I'll find, try & tell way 4, 5, etc.