# React deleted nextJS and can't build connection

Tags: reactjs

I have deleted NextJS from my dependencies, deleted the nextjsconfig file and also reinstalled the node modules again. I also added the App.js and index.js file again to the source directory.

As I am trying to start the app - My browser tells me, that I Can't build a connection to localhost:3000.

I am also using Docker.

Anyone an idea?

Very best regards
Michael

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745015/8434997 may this help