# how to build nextjs app unable to build and deploy

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, build

when i am running npm run build command then getting this error

```
D:\SPR\Porfolio\developer-portfolio>npm run build
> developer-portfolio@0.1.0 build
> next build    ▲ Next.js 14.1.3    Creating an optimized production build ...  ✓ Compiled successfully  ✓ Linting and checking validity of types  ✓ Collecting page data  ✓ Generating static pages (5/5)  ✓ Collecting build traces  ✓ Finalizing page optimization Route (app)    Size     First Load JS ┌ ○ /                                    93.4 kB         191 kB └ ○ /_not-found                          882 B      
85.2 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            84.4 kB   ├ chunks/69-8cf8699d03dbafa6.js        29 kB   ├ chunks/fd9d1056-1b06546f2a6b6797.js  53.4 kB   └ other shared chunks (total)          1.97 kB ○  (Static)  prerendered as static content
```

here is package.json file. i am unable to build the NextJs Project. i have tried many solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712936/how-to-build-next-js-production) but didn't work. because of the build failed issue i am also unable to deploy the nextjs app on github too.

```
{
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/portfolio",
  "name": "developer-portfolio",
  "description": "Portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^4.3.1",
    "@next/third-parties": "^14.1.3",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "next": "^14.1.3",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.6.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.4",
    "sharp": "^0.33.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "tailwindcss": "latest"
  }
}
```